# Javascript to change Image URL based on Even or Odd ID

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to have two different default images based on if the request ID is even or odd.

This is the code I have right now.

```
 <span style="float:right; strong;">ID#</strong> '.$row['id'].'</span> <br/>
 <br />

 <img src="pics/comingsoon_new.png" width="400px" height="200px" 
 onerror=this.style.display="none" <br /><br /><br />
```

Is there a way to add javascript so it would change the default image url page on if the ID is even or odd?

Comment: Which ID are you talking about?

Comment: Also I suggest removing the PHP tag...

Comment: @KidDoesCodingAnd HasNoFriends I am referring to the $row['id']

Comment: Also your code does not seem to be valid HTML. What are you using?

Comment: @KidDoesCodingAnd HasNoFriends it isn't html it is php. My code works fine. I am trying to find out if anyone know of a way (if even possible) to use javascript to have my default image url change based on the id being even or odd. I did a lot of research and couldn't find anything so I figured I would try here.

Comment: Maybe it's better to do this on the backend with PHP?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `modulo` to check if an `int` is even or odd. Here is a quick example using js/jquery.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Put value of php to js
    var id = <?php echo $row['id'];?>;

    //Use modulo to check if even or odd
    if ( id % 2 ) {
        //Odd - Change the attr for img
        $( "img" ).attr( "src", "pics/comingsoon_new-odd.png" );
    } else {
        //Even - Change the attr for img
        $( "img" ).attr( "src", "pics/comingsoon_new-even.png" );
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: what would i put here <img src="pics/comingsoon_new.png" in order to make the js work?

Comment: @Reed You can use the default/any src by default. You can also leave it blank. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <span style="float:right; strong;">ID#</strong> '.$row['id'].'</span> <br/> <br />
<?php $img_url = $row['id'] % 2 == 0 ? 'Even_img_url' :'odd_img_url'; ?>

 <img src="<?php echo $img_url; ?>" width="400px" height="200px" onerror=this.style.display="none" <br /><br /><br />
```

If it's coming from server side why you need to do it with js?